# How to make Excel treat days/dates as starting at 8 p.m. rather than 12 a.m

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

Our 24-hour day is 8PM to 7:59PM. That's considered 1 day, not 12AM to 11:59PM. For times after 8PM, I need the entries to be considered part of the next day.  For example:

```
    Actual Date/Time    How Excel should treat it

    30-Sep  11:52 PM    1-Oct  +3:52
     1-Oct   6:00 AM    1-Oct +10:00 
     2-Oct   7:00 AM    2-Oct +11:00
```

How do I make Excel see September 30 11:52pm as Oct 1, along with 6:00AM, as the first few hours of operation rather than the end of the day?

Answer (score 0):

#### The simplest approach would be to translate the times and then calculate normally.

Your daily start time is 4 hours prior to the "standard" definition of a day.  If you shift the times forward by four hours, they will match the definition that Excel is designed to work with normally.  Think of it this way: if it is 8PM on September 30 for you, it is the start of October 1 for someone in a time zone four hours to your east.  It's equivalent to having them do your real-time data entry.  It doesn't change the relationship between the times, it is more like formatting them to a different time zone.

#### Implementation

**Time Offset Value**

When you have a constant that is re-used, and especially if you might ever need to change it, it is good practice to store the value in one place and maintain it there.  That avoids having to change a hard-coded value in many locations, and also potential typos.  Then you refer to that value in the formulas.

In some other portion of the spreadsheet, say X1, you could put a label, like `time offset:`, and in Y1 put the 4 hour value.  A user-friendly way to do this is to enter in Y1: `=TIME(4,0,0)`. That's equal to the value of four hours, zero minutes, and zero seconds.

**Time Translation**

So if A1 contains the actual date/time, the formula in B1 would be:

```
=A1+$Y$1
```

In your example, you show the date and time in separate columns.  It isn't clear whether this is just formatting applied to duplicate date/time values, or the cells contain just a date or a time.  If it is the latter, you can simply combine them in your formula.  So the formula would go into C1 as:

```
=A1+B1+$Y$1
```

Enter the formula for the first cell and then copy it down for the whole data range.  The dollar signs anchor the Y1 reference so that it doesn't adjust as you copy the formula to other cells.

The new column will then contain the translated values that you work with.  (If the result appears as a number, just format the cells as a date/time.)

If you are just using the values for time calculations, like time difference, these values can be used directly and the calculations will be correct.  If you need to display a translated time as the actual time, just do the reverse.  The displayed value would be the translated value minus four hours.  For example:

```
=C1-$Y$1
```

Comment: Thanks.Is that feasible for huge amount of data?

Comment: That's probably the simplest way to do it for a large amount of data.  Just copy the formula across the whole data range.

Comment: (1) I would suggest putting the time offset value (`1/6`) in one place, such as cell `TT1`, and then using that in all your other formulas (e.g., `=A1+TT1`). That way, if you ever need to change the offset value (e.g., if your company moves to another time zone), you need to change it in only one place rather than thousands. (2) If you would like to use something more intuitive and (arguably) maintainable than `1/6`, consider `TIME(4,0,0)`. That's equal to the value of four hours, zero minutes and zero seconds (which is equal to 1/6 of a day).